# Проблема с переносом бота на aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot

Как и многие, я написал своего первого бота на pyTelegramBotAPI, но вот с публикацией бота я понял, что допустил ошибку в самом начале при выборе библиотеки. О преимуществах aiogram говорить нет смысла.

Но при переносе кода на новую библиотеку я столкнулся с проблемой: один из моих методов я не смог сделать async.

В данном примере я сократил код до минимума, чтобы акцентировать внимание именно на проблемном методе.
Вкратце расскажу, что он делает: у пользователя есть возможность поставить таймер на 10 секунд, и по окончании таймера бот сообщает пользователю об этом (ну и может выполнить некоторые действия). У пользователя же есть возможность прервать таймер, завершив его принудительно (при этом действия после таймера все равно будут выполнены). При этом у пользователя есть возможность включать этот таймер потом бесконечное количество раз.

Как это все перенести на aiogram, я так и не смог придумать. Если сможете дать пример кода, буду очень благодарен.

Сам метод таймера взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds)

```
API_TOKEN = '--'
bot = TeleBot(API_TOKEN)


def setinterval(interval):   #сам таймер
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            stopped = threading.Event()

            def loop():  # executed in another thread
                while not stopped.wait(interval):
                    function(*args, **kwargs)

            t = threading.Thread(target=loop)
            t.daemon = True  
            t.start()
            return stopped

        return wrapper

    return decorator

@setinterval(10)
def tim(chat_id): # метод, который выполняется после таймера
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    key = types.KeyboardButton(text="Запустить таймер")
    keyboard.add(key)
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Таймер закончился!', reply_markup=keyboard)
    obj.timer.set()



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_command_handler(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    key = types.KeyboardButton(text="Запустить таймер")
    keyboard.add(key)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Это старт, нажми на кнопку, чтобы запустить таймер', reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.message_handler()
def start_timer(message: types.Message):
    if (message.text == 'Запустить таймер'):
        keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        key = types.KeyboardButton(text="Остановить таймер")
        keyboard.add(key)
        obj.timer = tim(message.chat.id)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Таймер запущен. Нажми на кнопку, чтобы остановить', reply_markup=keyboard)
    if (message.text == 'Остановить таймер'):
        keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        key = types.KeyboardButton(text="Запустить таймер")
        keyboard.add(key)
        obj.timer.set()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Таймер остановлен. Нажми на кнопку, чтобы запустить его снова',
                         reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример того как бы я сделал это

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def task(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add("Запустить таймер")
    await message.answer('Это старт, нажми на кнопку, чтобы запустить таймер на 5 минут', reply_markup=markup)


@dp.message_handler(text='Запустить таймер')
def start_timer(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add("Остановить таймер")
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["start_timer"] = time()
    await message.answer('Таймер запущен. Нажми на кнопку, чтобы остановить', reply_markup=markup)
    
    await asyncio.sleep(5*60)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        if data.get("start_timer"):
            await message.answer("Время вышло!")


@dp.message_handler(text='Остановить таймер')
def start_timer(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add("Запустить таймер")
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        del data["start_timer"]
    await message.answer('Таймер остановлен. Нажми на кнопку, чтобы запустить его снова'
                         'Прошло времени', reply_markup=markup)
```